# for-loop for a big matrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have a matrix `ALL` that is 94968x8.

At the 2nd column I have months(1-12) and at the 4th column I have hours(0-23).
So, I want to create new matrices (`B`), with elements from the 5th column.

For example, I want the elements (from 5th column) which correspond at January `1` and time `0`. Then the elements which correspond at January `1` and time `1`, etc. This for all months and all times.

I have this program

```
MONTH_COL_NUM = 2;

HOUR_COL_NUM = 4;

SELECT_COL = 5;

B = ALL(ALL(:,MONTH_COL_NUM) == 1 & ALL(:,HOUR_COL_NUM) == 0, SELECT_COL);
```

But I don't know how to use `'for'` correctly.

[My Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th0dt.png)

Comment: If you already have a Matrix with all combinations, it looks like you just need to sort it. Then you will have the rows in chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

Here a code for this:

```
featureAVal = 1; %<! Month
featureACol = 2;
featureBVal = 0; %<! Hour
featureBCol = 5;

vFeatureAIdx = mA(:, featureACol) == featureAVal;
vFeatureBIdx = mA(:, featureBCol) == featureBVal;

vSelectedRows = vFeatureAIdx & vFeatureBIdx;

mB = mA(vSelectedRows, 5);
```

Enjoy...